# Getting image appearing properly in readme file using include with Sphinx

Tags: github, python-sphinx

I want to include an image in my readme.rst file and have it appear correctly both on Github and in the documentation generated by Sphinx on ReadTheDocs

The file structure is as follows:

```
readme.rst         # first readme
docs/
    index.rst
    readme.rst     # second readme
    images/
         my_image.png
```

The second readme file contains

```
.. include:: ../readme.rst
```

If I specify the path for my_image in the first readme file as

```
.. image:: images/my_image.png
```

It appears correctly in the documentation generated by sphinx, both locally and on the ReadTheDocs site.  However, it does not appear in the readme section on Github.

To have it appear on Github, I need to change the path to

```
.. image:: docs/images/my_image.png
```

but it then no longer appears on the local sphinx built nor on the ReadTheDocs site.

Of course this makes perfect sense ... However, is there any trick/configuration settings that can be used so that the path for the image can be written and interpreted correctly everwhere (while still using the ..include directive for Sphinx)?

Comment: As a workaround, I created an images directory off the main directory and simply copied the relevant images.  Since images are not updated as often as the rest of the documentation, it seemed to be the least error-prone option.